# How can I change background color of razor syntax in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I want to change the background color of razor code inside cshtml to recognize it faster when I'm scrolling. I want to change whole text not only @.
How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors` then you can change the `Razor Directive` (@) to be more visible and perhaps `HTML Attribute Name` and `HTML Element Name` to be less visible. I think the rest of the razor code has the same color as normal code, so you could also change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve my issue. I went to tools>options>Text Editor>HTML>Advanced and turn legacy razor editor to true. Now I have what I want.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to change the background color.

```
 @model MyViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Page</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: white;
        }
        
        #content {
            /* your content styles here */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- your dynamic content here -->
    </div>
    
    <script>
        const content = document.getElementById("content");
        
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
                content.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
            } else {
                content.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

use Razor syntax to generate the HTML and CSS for the page, including a #content div for our dynamic content. Then, we add a JavaScript block to the bottom of the page that listens for the "scroll" event and updates the background color of the #content div accordingly.

Comment: ty for your reply, but its not my answer. It seems you did not read my question carefully.